# Whch Google API Client service(s) do I need for managing In App purchases?

Tags: google-api-php-client

The client library is huge and [this page](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/README.md#installation) says I can just specify the specific API(s) I need, but which ones do I need?

I just want to manage In App purchases.  I've made it work by installing the whole library using the composer.json file

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

(yes, I know that's a slightly old version) but that loads 48Mb of files!  Can I reduce this by specifying just the required services? If so, which one(s)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only library required is "Pubsub".

How to know what services there are?  If you've installed everything then you can see the full list of services under your vendor/apiclient-services/src/ directory.  Each service has its own directory.

If you haven't, you can find this list in the repository google-api-php-client-services on GitHub. If you're using something other than php, then replace "php" with the language you're using.